# Fetching Dynamic Website Data Using Java

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html

I am currently using Java (Eclipse) to build this application which will be able to take a spans value from a specific website and show those values on console. But the issue i am having is, the Website i believe is Dynamic and therefore, i am not able to get those span values. The span (id=spot) keeps refreshing every 1 second and i guess it uses JavaScript. The class keeps auto changing as well when i do a "Inspect element". But if i do "View page source", there is no value inside the span. Could anyone suggest anyway to either render the web page and fetch data or any other method to do this. I have been 
on google for the past 2 hours and nothing helped. I am new to this selenuim, JSoup, rhino which did not help at all. So please try to elaborate as much as you can :)

Here is the Web Page: https://www.binary.com/trading?l=EN

span id=spot

Comment: If the contents is dynamic, chances are that the javascript is querying a web service. See if you can find the code that does the querying.

Comment: I already have the query file taken from the website source. But what to do with that? Please help

Comment: Look at the javascript code

Comment: I am sorry but i do not see where you're going with this. The javascript is on page source linked to a script file. At the moment i can not access the file as im on my mobile. Could you please elaborate what to do next after i find the javascript file?

Comment: @MauricePerry Here is the link to the script file. what to do next?

https://static.binary.com/js/binary.min.js?13b386b