# How to take span value from website which stores data dynamically using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsoup

I am new to this so could anyone point me to the right direction? 
I have a JavaScript file by which i want to take the value of a span from a website. Now the website dynamically refreshes the span every 1 second. I am using Java (Eclipse) to fetch this data. When i try to take the span value from website, it gives me no values because the span uses JavaScript to store these values. I already asked this question and i will drop a link below. So all i want to know is, how to take this data dynamically using JSoup. Someone commented on my last post saying the JavaScript might be querying a web service and to find that code. But i could not find the code and i don't know what to do next.

Here is the link to my last question: [Fetching Dynamic Website Data Using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36788291/fetching-dynamic-website-data-using-java?noredirect=1#comment61158398_36788291)

Here is the link to the website which stores data i want in a span named "id=spot" (Basically numeric numbers of stock): https://www.binary.com/trading?l=EN

And finally here is the link to the JavaScript file of the website which have all the functions: https://static.binary.com/js/binary.min.js?13b386b

Please help me as i am very new to this and i have spent more than 2 days trying to find the answer with no luck.
Thank you in advance

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------.---------------------------------------------------

Okay so the first part of the question is solved but i am having another issue now. I copied this code but i am getting this error now. Here is my code:

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.InterruptedException;
import javax.websocket.*;

@ClientEndpoint
public class WSClient  {

@OnOpen
public void onOpen(Session session) throws java.io.IOException
{
    session.getBasicRemote().sendText("{\"ticks\": \"R_100\"}");
}

@OnMessage
public void onMessage(String message)
{
    System.out.println("ticks update: " + message);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
    throws IOException, DeploymentException, InterruptedException
{
    WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
    URI apiUri = URI.create("wss://ws.binaryws.com/websockets/v3");
    Session session = container.connectToServer(WSClient.class, apiUri);
    Thread.sleep(10000);
}
}
```

And here is the error on console:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find an implementation class.
>       at javax.websocket.ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer(ContainerProvider.java:73)
>       at WSClient.main(WSClient.java:24)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This site is using WebSockets to retrieve the data from server to show in the client:

```
var onLoad = function(){
        trading_page = 1;
        if(sessionStorage.getItem('currencies')){
            displayCurrencies();
        }       
        BinarySocket.init({
            onmessage: function(msg){
                Message.process(msg); //this function is updating that sppan
            },
            onclose: function(){
                processMarketUnderlying();
            }
        });
        Price.clearFormId();
        TradingEvents.init();
        Content.populate();
```

So you can not see the data in downloaded HTML with JSOUP. You need a UI-less Browser in java like [HTML-UNIT](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/).

But the preferred and more reasonable way is to use the [API of the site](https://developers.binary.com/).

Comment: Could you please state a code to use API? Like i said i am very new at this :/

Comment: they have code samples for different languages Including java : https://developers.binary.com/demos/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Helped me a lot. But i am having another issue. i have edited my question above.

Comment: Post it as a new question please.